# Upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 Configuring Postgresql-Common Issue

Tags: 15.10, 16.04, postgresql

I am currently at a loss right now while upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 in Ubuntu.  I currently can't take screen shots because I am right in the middle of the upgrading the distribution and my screenshot tool is broken.  For some reason the installer froze and came up with the following message while installing the upgrades:

"Package Configuration

Configuring postgresql - common

Obsolete Major Version 9.4

The PostgreSQL version 9.4 is obsolete, but the server or client packages are installed.  Please install the latest packages (postgresql-9.5 and postgresql-client-9.5) and upgrade the existing cluster with pg_upgradeclsuter (see manpage).

Please be aware that installation of postgresql-9.5 will automatically create a default cluster 9.5/main.  If you want to upgrade the 9.4 main cluster, you need to remove the already existing 9.5 cluster (pg_dropcluster --stop 9.5 main, see manpage for details).

The old server and client packages are no longer supported.  After the existing clusters are upgrade, the postgresql-9.4 and postgres-client-9.4 packages should be removed.

Please see /usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.Debian.gz for details."

The above message is given if you click on the terminal drop down.  However it is not displayed in the terminal. It is a message box with a purple background in the back.

Unfortunately, I have have pressed control-C and tried to abort the operation.  However the distribution upgrade box is still up there and the message is still being displayed so I am hoping I can still fix this.  I honestly don't care if I have to get rid of postgresql now and reinstall it later, I just want my install to continue.

Does any one know how to solve this problem???

Comment: I just press Ctrl+ Enter

Answer (score 3):

[image: problem screenshot]
I encountered exactly the problem described (see screenshot). I finally could solve it but I cannot exactly describe "how". Playing around and resizing the "distribution upgrade" window, at some point I could make a cursor appear in the terminal. Then pressing an arrow key, I could highlight the "Ok" in red. Then I hit "enter" and the installation resumed.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to scroll using arrow keys, press tab, then press enter.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, here is the solution

1) Click on upgrade installation window
2) Press tab button - that will highlight the  button
3) Hit enter button and upgrade window will continue the installation process...

Comment: Thanks to all of you for both posting and providing a solution. Why can't they make these things a little more obvious so we don't stress and waste time trying to find an answer? I'm just saying....

Comment: What a hell!) You saved me!!! I have been trying to update PostgreSQL for last 70 minutes! What an idiot created this horrible UI?! I have pressed the enter button, I clicked to the LmC and nothing, and why?! Because I didn't press the f*cking tab button between them! Seriously, thank you very much! You saved my nervous!